# How does jquery map to the init function in this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, self-invoking-function

Hi all I am trying to understand the code below. I understand that it is a self invoking function. And in the end when the document is ready the `methodDraw.init` method is being called

```
(function() {

    if(!window.methodDraw) window.methodDraw = function($) {
      var svgCanvas;
      var Editor = {};
      var is_ready = false;
      var curConfig = {
        canvas_expansion: 1, 
        dimensions: [580,400], 
        initFill: {color: 'fff', opacity: 1},
        initStroke: {width: 1.5, color: '000', opacity: 1},
        initOpacity: 1,
        imgPath: 'images/',
        extPath: 'extensions/',
        jGraduatePath: 'lib/jgraduate/images/',
        extensions: [],
        initTool: 'select',
        wireframe: false,
        colorPickerCSS: false,
        gridSnapping: false,
        gridColor: "#000",
        baseUnit: 'px',
        snappingStep: 10,
        showRulers: (svgedit.browser.isTouch()) ? false : true,
        show_outside_canvas: false,
        no_save_warning: true,
        initFont: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif'
      };
      var curPrefs = {}; //$.extend({}, defaultPrefs);
      var customHandlers = {};
      Editor.curConfig = curConfig;
      Editor.tool_scale = 1;

      Editor.setConfig = function(opts) {
        $.extend(true, curConfig, opts);
        if(opts.extensions) {
          curConfig.extensions = opts.extensions;
        }
      }      

      Editor.init = function() {

        // For external openers
        (function() {
          console.log("inside editor.init")
          // let the opener know SVG Edit is ready
          var w = window.opener;
          if (w) {
                try {
              var methodDrawReadyEvent = w.document.createEvent("Event");
              methodDrawReadyEvent.initEvent("methodDrawReady", true, true);
              w.document.documentElement.dispatchEvent(methodDrawReadyEvent);
                }
            catch(e) {}
          }
        })();        
      };  
      return Editor;
    }(jQuery);    

    // Run init once DOM is loaded
    $(methodDraw.init);
    console.log("inside methoddraw.init")

  })();
```

What I fail to understand is, how does methodDraw equate to Editor? how does `methodDraw.init` call `Editor.init`?. In the console the methodDraw message is followed by the editor message. Or am I getting it completely wrong. Kindly bear with me as I am just starting off with jQuery.

Comment: The `Editor` is returned at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code snippet if you look closely to `window.methodDraw`, it is a function, and at the end it will return `Editor` object instance that was configured and prepared throughout `window.methodDraw` function body, so since this instance object already have init method you can directly chain the call to it, here is a little snippet to demonstrate it in a simple way:

```js
let Editor = {};

Editor.init = () => {
 console.log('Editor.init');
}

let InitializerObj = (() => {
  return Editor;
})()

InitializerObj.init();
```